# document.forms.submit is hanging my page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am making a website that helps manipulate an SQL table. At the moment, I want to be able to reload my page but with some new variables. The way I've done it is by making a form (called rerouter) with a few hidden textareas and an action which is just the current page (in this instance, "connect.php"). Like so:

```
    <form action='connect.php' method='post' id='rerouter'>
        <input type='hidden' name='foo' id='foo'></input>
        <input type='hidden' name='bar' id='bar'></input>
        <input type='hidden' name='foobar' id='foobar'></input>
    </form>
```

When it comes time to reload the page I populate those textareas with the new values I'll want, then I submit the form, like this (the getRequest() calls another PHP file which just creates an SQL string and executes it. I'm just including it here to show that there's logic before the rerouting process which still executes):

```
    ...
    getRequest(str, succ, err);

    document.getElementById('foo').value = fooText;
    document.getElementById('foo').value = barTest;
    document.getElementById('foobar').value = foobarText;
    document.forms['rerouter'].submit();
```

This works great, except on occasion the whole page freezes. The only way to unfreeze it is to reload the page, then it prompts you with the "Oh, snap" error (in Chrome) which you need to reload. The getRequest() still occurs fine, but the code hangs somewhere after. I have not found a way to consistently reproduce the problem except for calling this function over and over until it finally fails, but I will keep you all informed if I discover a pattern. Also, I do not have access to jQuery.

SOLUTION: @HaukurHaf pointed out I was using an asynchronous AJAX call unstably. On occasion the PHP called by getRequest() had not finished when forms.submit() was called. I moved some code around so my main function looks like:

```
            ...
    document.getElementById('foo').value = fooText;
    document.getElementById('foo').value = barTest;
    document.getElementById('foobar').value = foobarText;

    getRequest(str, succ, err);
```

and my succ function looks like:

```
    function succ() {
        document.forms['rerouter'].submit();
    }
```

(it was empty before). Now the form won't submit until we're absolutely sure the PHP has finished executing.

Comment: What does getRequest() do?  Is it an asynchronous AJAX call perhaps?  If so, the following code would need to be executed in a callback function.

Comment: It is an AJAX call, but I don't know what would classify it as asynchronous. It makes an XMLHttpRequest and then calls open() and send() on it. The url it calls it on is a php page that copies a whole bunch of SQL data from one table to another.

Comment: Ok, it's asyncronous by default so unless you are explicitly telling it otherwise, it is.  That basically means that the getRequest() method will not always run completely since the browser immediately tries to submit the form.  This could also cause the behaviour you are describing.  The correct way would be to have getRequest() accept a callback function which is executed once the request is finished.  The form submit code should then be moved into that callback function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to this whole website end of coding, and this AJAX stuff doesn't sit right with me, so this was incredibly helpful! I went ahead and shuffled some stuff so getRequest() is the end of my function, and the submit() is in the succ function. Like I said, I never had a guaranteed way to reproduce the problem, so I can't be 1000% sure, but I just ran it about 50 times and it didn't hang once so I think that did it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I actually added my comment as an answer so you could mark it as an accepted solution/upvote it - just to help others as well ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is getRequest() doing? Is it doing an async AJAX call?

That basically means that the getRequest() method will not always run completely since the browser immediately tries to submit the form. This could also cause the behaviour you are describing. The correct way would be to have getRequest() accept a callback function which is executed once the request is finished. The form submit code should then be moved into that callback function.